# Progress Dialog Condition for videoview

Tags: java, android

i am trying to make the condition "when the dialog will be dismissed then auto play the video..." with the bellow code , i was accomplished to do that but the videoview doesnt auto play... can you suggest something?

mycode.java

```
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlayVideo.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please set the pyramid");
        // Set progressbar message
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // Show progressbar
        progressDialog.show();



        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        Uri uri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("uri");

        try {
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {


                if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.cancel();
                        }
                    };

                    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
                    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);
                }

                if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    myVideoView.seekTo(position);
                     if (position == 0) {
                         myVideoView.start();
                     }
                     else {
                         myVideoView.pause();
                     }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `onPreparedListener` only gets called **once** when the media is ready for playback. So when it is ready your code executes checks if the dialog is showing or not and does accordingly. What you need to do is set an `setOnDismissListener()` on the progress dialog. And when you dismiss it then play the video. Or are you trying to show the dialog till video is ready?

Comment: i need to show the dialog first and then the video play... can you make it as an answer with code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will dismiss your dialog once the video is ready and play the video

```
    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {

      Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          progressDialog.cancel();
          myVideoView.seekTo(position);
          if (position == 0) {
            myVideoView.start();
          } else {
            myVideoView.pause();
          }
        }
      };
      Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
      pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);
    }
```

I don't know why you are pausing. If you can explain what exactly is the flow that you are trying to implement then I can help better